# Mutation Testing Tools for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mutation-testing

Is there any mutation testing tools from C# on visual studio 2015?
Visual Mutator is not working with visual studio 2015 ([link to github issue](https://github.com/visualmutator/visualmutator/issues/1))

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/pavzaj/visualmutator

Please check my fork. It is not release ready, but somehow works with VS2015 and nunit 3.

Comment: I have added a pre-relase page to this branch:
https://github.com/pavzaj/visualmutator/releases

Please use vsix installer.

Comment: Is there any chance of this being recompiled for vs2017? I'm encountered a bug when trying to compile from your source, is there a bin file missing? https://github.com/pavzaj/visualmutator/issues/6